# VBA 2D Array for each item find average value

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am trying to find a way to average an array column value with a condition on items from another column in that array - I am aware that a class or dictionary might be the best solution but I would like to stick to an array as in my real scenario I have to use an array.

In this case the data is as follows

```
Risk ID    Data set 1    Data set 2

23359720   1154          587
23359720   1254          658
23359720   854           756
23293773   965           1456
20053692   1458          458
```

I would like to find the average of Data sets 1 and 2 per Risk ID, here is what I've tried but does not work - I have seen that this it's not possible to use for each and point it to a specific column, but not sure what else to do in the case of an array?

```
Edit: expected result data:

ArrayResultAverage()

    Risk ID    Avg Data set 1    Avg Data set 2
    
    23359720   1087.33          667
    23293773   965              1456
    20053692   1458             458


Sub Test_Arr_Avg()
'
Dim TESTWB As Workbook
Dim TESTWS As Worksheet

Set TESTWB = ThisWorkbook
Set TESTWS = TESTWB.Worksheets("TEST")


'Array set up

Dim RngTest As Range
Dim ArrTestAvg As Variant

NbRowsTest = TESTWS.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

Set RngTest = TESTWS.Range(TESTWS.Cells(1, 1), TESTWS.Cells(NbRowsTest, 3))


ArrTestAvg = RangeToArray2D(RngTest)


 'Find the average of Data Range 1 for each item in Risk ID

For k = 1 To UBound(ArrTestAvg, 1)
   
        Dim Sum As Variant
        Sum = 0

        For Each Item In ArrTestAvg(k, 1)

        Sum = Sum + ArrTestAvg(k, 2)

        Dim AverageDataSet1 As Variant

        AverageDataSet1 = Sum / UBound(ArrTestAvg(Item)) + 1
        
        Debug.Print AverageDataSet1
        
        Next Item

   Next k

End Sub

Public Function RangeToArray2D(inputRange As Range) As Variant()
Dim size As Integer
Dim inputValue As Variant, outputArray() As Variant

    inputValue = inputRange

    On Error Resume Next
    size = UBound(inputValue)

    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        RangeToArray2D = inputValue
    Else
        On Error GoTo 0
        ReDim outputArray(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        outputArray(1, 1) = inputValue
        RangeToArray2D = outputArray
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
```

End Function

Comment: Do you need the average for each Risk ID?

Comment: Could you share the code of the `RangeToArray2D` procedure? Also, using the provided sample data, could you share the expected result with a brief description of the math behind it?

Comment: See edit with RangeToArray2D, I would want the average of each data set per Risk ID - for example average of Risk ID 23359720 for Data set 1 (average of 1154, 1254, 854)

Comment: You have nicely shared your source data. Could you present the result for this data in the same way? I don't understand where you want to put it, is it three new columns with 3 rows of results in another/the same worksheet? Please do clarify.

Comment: @VBasic2008 see my edit, I was thinking debug.print as a start but in fact my end goal would be an array containing risk ID (1) Avg Data Set 1 (2) Avg Data Set (3)

Comment: That's more like it. I'll look into it in a couple of hours. Sorry, busy at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

### Get Averages of Unique Data

- Adjust the values in the constants section, especially the destination worksheet name (it's the same as the source worksheet name) and its first cell address.
- The dictionary's keys hold the unique risk ids, while its items (values) hold the associated destination rows.
- The result is written to the same array (which is too big) but with `dr` the destination row size is tracked and only three columns will be copied.
- Before the calculation of the averages, column 1 holds the unique risk ids (the same order as in the dictionary), columns 2 and 3 hold the sums while columns 4 and 5 hold the counts of the first and second data set respectively.

```vb
Option Explicit


Sub Test_Arr_Avg()
    
    ' Source
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    ' Destination
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "E1"
    ' Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Read from source.
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim slRow As Long: slRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Range("A1", sws.Cells(slRow, "C"))
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = srg.Rows.Count
    
    ' Write source range values to array.
    Dim Data As Variant: Data = GetRange(srg)
    ' Add two helper columns for the count.
    ReDim Preserve Data(1 To srCount, 1 To 5)
    
    ' Sum up and count uniques.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim dr As Long: dr = 1 ' first row are headers
    
    Dim sr As Long
    Dim cr As Long
    Dim c As Long
    
    For sr = 2 To srCount
        ' Sum up.
        If dict.Exists(Data(sr, 1)) Then
            cr = dict(Data(sr, 1))
            For c = 2 To 3
                Data(cr, c) = Data(cr, c) + Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        Else
            dr = dr + 1
            cr = dr
            dict(Data(sr, 1)) = cr
            For c = 1 To 3
                Data(cr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
        ' Count.
        For c = 4 To 5
            Data(cr, c) = Data(cr, c) + 1
        Next c
    Next sr
    
    ' Calculate averages.
    
    For cr = 2 To dr
        For c = 2 To 3
            Data(cr, c) = Data(cr, c) / Data(cr, c + 2)
            ' You might want to round the results instead:
            'Data(cr, c) = Round(Data(cr, c) / Data(cr, c + 2), 2)
        Next c
    Next cr
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Write to destination.
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    With dws.Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, 3)
        .Resize(dr).Value = Data
        ' Clear below.
        .Resize(dws.Rows.Count - .Row - dr + 1).Offset(dr).Clear
        ' Apply various formatting.
        .Font.Bold = True ' headers
        .Resize(dr - 1, 2).Offset(1, 1).NumberFormat = "#0.00" ' averages
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit ' columns
    End With

    'wb.Save

    ' Inform.
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Risk ids averaged.", vbInformation

End Sub


''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Returns the values of a range ('rg') in a 2D one-based array.
' Remarks:      If ˙rg` refers to a multi-range, only its first area
'               is considered.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function GetRange( _
    ByVal rg As Range) _
As Variant
    Const ProcName As String = "GetRange"
    On Error GoTo ClearError
    
    If rg.Rows.Count + rg.Columns.Count = 2 Then ' one cell
        Dim Data As Variant: ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = rg.Value
        GetRange = Data
    Else ' multiple cells
        GetRange = rg.Value
    End If

ProcExit:
    Exit Function
ClearError:
    Debug.Print "'" & ProcName & "' Run-time error '" _
        & Err.Number & "':" & vbLf & "    " & Err.Description
    Resume ProcExit
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be complicated to use a single Dictionary.  Here I add a Sub-Dictionary for each Risk ID to the main Dictionary.  The Sub-Dictionary is used to hold all the values for each ID.  The final step is to create an array of averages for all the main Dictionary items.

[image: Test Data]

```
Sub Test_Arr_Avg()
    Dim Data As Variant
    With TestWS.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        Data = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 3)
    End With
    Dim Results As Variant
    
    Results = KeyedAverages(Data, 1, 2)
    Stop
End Sub

Function KeyedAverages(Data As Variant, IDColumn As Long, ValueColumn As Long)
    Dim Map As Object
    Set Map = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        
    Dim Key As Variant
    Dim r As Long
        
    For r = 1 To UBound(Data)
        Key = CStr(Data(r, IDColumn))
        If Len(Key) > 0 Then
            If Not Map.Exists(Key) Then Map.Add Key, CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            With Map(Key)
                .Add CStr(.Count), Data(r, ValueColumn)
            End With
        End If
    Next
        
    Dim Results As Variant
    Dim Values As Variant
        
    ReDim Results(1 To Map.Count, 1 To 2)
    Dim n As Long
    For Each Key In Map.Keys
        n = n + 1
        Values = Map(Key).Items
        Results(n, 1) = Key
        Results(n, 2) = WorksheetFunction.Average(Values)
    Next
        
    KeyedAverages = Results
End Function

Public Function TestWB() As Workbook
    Set TestWB = ThisWorkbook
End Function

Public Function TestWS() As Worksheet
    Set TestWS = TestWB.Worksheets("Test")
End Function
```

**Note**: Code updated to exclude empty items.

Comment: thanks this function works, however I have one question if I want to exclude empty items in Map(Key).Items , how could I do that ?